# Duplicate headphones control buttons on an adapter

Tags: audio

I want to make an adapter which connects from one side to the TRRS headset plug, on the other side to the audio jack of my smartphone.
The adapter contains the same controls (three usual buttons) of the headset, no mic needed.
If I put it on the handlebar of my scooter it allows me to avoid leaving the handlebar with one hand.
Do you think it's possible to do it without breaking my current headset?
Many thanks

Comment: Yes, it will of course be possible :) Just replicate the circuit typically found in the controls of a pair of headphones.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy TRRS male and female (plug and socket) connectors, and wire it to a circuit which connects different resistances to the GND and MIC pins for play (direct short, i.e. 0 ohms), next and previous track (something like 30 ohms off the top of my d but it's probably way different). Measure the resistances across it and you can then build a circuit to do so.

Here is a basic circuit I've thought up which should work. The "something" resistances is what you measure between GND and MIC while pressing the 3 buttons one by one...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY9ZAK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I learned the other day you can flip tags in schematics just like every other component

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you for the tip! I have updated the diagram.

Comment: Many thanks, can I use these for the resistances values? https://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/samsung-galaxy-s4/92033d1384533534t-galaxy-s4-headset-mic-button-wiring-schematic-pinout-samsung-s4-headset-wiring-schematic-pinout.png

Comment: @QuickishFM Can I do it by taking the components from another headset (which eventually I have to break)?  This way I have to just buy the TRRS socket, some wire and then do the soldering

Comment: Yes, exactly, those small PCBs will have everything you need. Ensure you connect the wires correctly (I have seen first-hand that different headphones use different colour schemes with the same colours, this can be confusing). One small tip of advice - the headphone wire can be tinned by passing the end of the wire (~1mm from the end is enough) through a blob of solder on the end of a chisel-tip iron for about 5 seconds - this will burn through the insulation and tin it. You generally cannot (in my experiences) strip the insulation as you normally would unless its thicker headphone wire.

Comment: By the way that image link looks about right. I should warn you that iPhone and Android devices use different schemes for this though! iPhone/iPod earphones use capacitive components instead of purely resistive, but if its Android and you measure a similar resistance between GND and MIC then by all means it should be OK (should you choose to make it yourself). If you have a spare headphones with controls lying around then honestly I think this'll be easier as it will be just splicing together wires...

Comment: @QuickishFM mine is an iPhone! But I will do this, I take a spare headphone, try them with my iPhone and check if it works as expected. If it works then I just have to solder the right wires, yes not based on colours but on the images above. I will use a multimeter, something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Etekcity-Multimeter-MSR-R500-Electronic-Multimeters/dp/B01N9QW620/) is ok I think...

Comment: If you use an iPhone circuit with the iPhone headphones plugged into it, it should (theoretically) work. Any multimeter with continuity will do just fine.